# get content of a text file on internet, flutter

Tags: string, flutter, dart, httpclient, response

when i read the content of a text file that exist on an url on the internet , it's work just inside the function.

this is my function

```
String x="";
Future<String> ip(String url)
  async {
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    var request = await client.postUrl(Uri.parse(url));
    request.close().then((response) {
      utf8.decoder.bind(response.cast<List<int>>()).listen((content) {
        print(content);// output https://st03.sslstream.dlf.de/dlf/03/128/mp3/stream.mp3
setState(() {
  x = content; // value null
});
      });
    });
  }
```

so when i print the content of this file

```
http://opml.radiotime.com/Tune.ashx?id=s120806
```

the result will be

```
https://st03.sslstream.dlf.de/dlf/03/128/mp3/stream.mp3
```

but as you can see in my function i gave the value of the content to x Field

```
setState(() {
  x = content; // value null
});
```

so when i call the Function in initsstate and then print the x , the value will be null !.

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    ip("http://opml.radiotime.com/Tune.ashx?id=s120806"); //output  https://st03.sslstream.dlf.de/dlf/03/128/mp3/stream.mp3
    print(x); // output null
    super.initState();
    audioStart();
  }
```

so i need to give other Field or Property the Content of the response , or i want to let my Function to return a String not a Future and this String will be really the content of The Response as a String and it's not a null .

thanks in advance

Comment: what do you want to do with that `x` inside your custom `StatefulWidget`? to use it in some `Widget` built by `build()` method?

Comment: yes exactly, i need to call the x inside some Widget.

Comment: use [FutureBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html) then

Comment: x is null because while print statement prints x, the Future `ip` will wouldn't be even executed, for x to be not null, you have to await `ip` to be complete, bear in mind init doesn't support async

Comment: and to get the string simply use: `var response = await request.close(); return response.single.then(utf8.decode);`

Comment: or even better when using [http](https://pub.dev/packages/http) package: `Future<String> _initFuture() async {
var resp = await http.get('http:/...');
return resp.body; }`

Comment: thanks for your help pskink and Yadu , can you please help in this question also if you please have a time. 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64292444/including-the-content-of-the-url-inside-the-widget

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this,

```
  @override
  void initState() {
   initAsyncState();
  }
 
  void initAsyncState() async {
    await ip("http://opml.radiotime.com/Tune.ashx?id=s120806"); //output  https://st03.sslstream.dlf.de/dlf/03/128/mp3/stream.mp3
    print(x); // output will not be null
  }
```

use a `FutureBuilder` if you want to use the response in a widget